# Android ViewPager Fragment ImageView Glide Memory Leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-viewpager, out-of-memory, android-glide

I'm using `ViewPager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.
Each `Fragment` has `ImageView`'s.
`Glide` for loading Images:

```
Glide.with(fragment)//current Fragment
     .load(imageUrl)//URL String
     .dontAnimate()
     .skipMemoryCache(true)
     .into(imageView_N);
```

---

`ViewPager`'s `OffscreenPageLimit` is default (1);
So `OnDestroy` is calling for each `Fragment`.
But after sliding next and next `Fragment` MemoryHeap is increasing, but not releasing.
And finally `OutOfMemory`.

---

I know, it could be possible duplicate question, but any other post did not help me.

Comment: I meet the same problem. It will be great if someone can give me a hint.

Comment: After lots of debugging, I solved this problem through heap dump. In my case, even the fragment.onDestroy() is called, the fragment is still existing in the heap because some other class/method(like onClickListener) holds its reference, which obviously causes a memory leak. Hope this will help you somehow.

Comment: @xudshen so, how did you solve it then ? would you give us some idea to destroy that referances clearly ?

Comment: Check this article to find memory leaks: https://medium.com/@elsenovraditya/android-hunting-memory-leak-in-nested-fragments-inside-viewpager-fc1879904804